# Buildroot does not re-build modified files

Tags: build, buildroot

I am using an external tree for building for a Linux kernel to support driver development. I created a Config.in and a kernel_driver.mk, and everything seemed to work fine, while I still had compilation errors.
I iterated over and over "make driver-dirclean / make driver".
However, I have the impression (and now I verified this fact) that, once I could successfully build correctly once, then BR would NOT rebuild the files again, even if I introduce purposely errors in those files !!!
also the output shows:

```
  CC [M]  /home/adva/work/sfpnid-drv/buildroot/output/build/hal-1.0.0/kernel/helper.o
  LD [M]  /home/adva/work/sfpnid-drv/buildroot/output/build/hal-1.0.0/kernel/spidev.o
  Building modules, stage 2.
  MODPOST 1 modules
  CC [M]  /home/adva/work/sfpnid-drv/buildroot/output/build/hal-1.0.0/kernel/spidev.mod.o
  LD [M]  /home/adva/work/sfpnid-drv/buildroot/output/build/hal-1.0.0/kernel/spidev.ko
```

The compilation never fails where it should !

Is there a cache issue somehow ? rsync effect ?

Comment: sorry for the badly formatted message .... it caught me by surprise :(

Answer (score 1):

finally i traced down the source of the problem.
As I am using an off-tree build, I had a "make clean" issue. I realise that the dependencies are solved in the BR/output/build/.. environement, while my files are edited off tree.
So what happens is, once it has built successfully 1 time, then the .o are present in BR. The dependencies are satisfied, the "make -rebuild would just re-link the old .o.
I need to do a "make -dirclean" so the new files (with errors) are rsynced.

This is at least the way i understood it.
So for me, this is kinda solved. The fact is, BR is really an integration tool, and less a developement environement. So this behavior is understandable.

Jacques

Comment: try `make linux-rebuild`, in my linux, rsync will get involved